# Cursor-movement after $ motion

Tags: cursor-movement

I play the great game called [VIM adventures](https://vim-adventures.com/) (from which are the images bellow). The question is from the game, but is also reproducible in VIM so this is the place I ask.

Assume you are in `normal mode`, standing on some line `n` and column `m`. If you press key `j`, your position becomes line `n+1` and same column `m`. If the line `n+1` has less columns than `m`, say `o`, you are placed at column `o`. Again press `j`. You are moved to line `n+2`, on column `m` (same check as before). See, column you started at, `m`, is remembered. This can be seen on the first image, with red lines representing `j` movement.

However, if you are in `normal mode` and press key `$`, you are moved to the end of the current line. Now consider the same sequence of movements as desribed in paragraph before. Each movement `j` will move you to the last character on that line. `m` is not remembered in this case. This can be seen on the second image. By pressing first `$`, coursor is placed at the end of the first line. Then, by pressing multiple `j` movements, each lands coursor on the end of line, ignoring `m`, which was remembered in the first paragraph.

I can't find this in any VIM documentation. Can you explain me how this *remembering mechanism* works or point me to the part of documentation which explains this ?

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Special thanks to a simple, precise and unambiguous description of the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there are not very direct references to this behavior in the documentation of the [`$`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%24) command itself.

The documentation of the [`g$`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#g%24) motion actually refers to this behavior though, in explaining how `g$` differs from `$`:

> Differs from `$` when the last character of the line is not on the screen or when a count is used. Additionally, **vertical movements keep the column, instead of going to the end of the line.**

Other than through documentation, you can take a peek at how Vim actually *implements* this column tracking, since functions such as [`getcurpos()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getcurpos%28%29) export that information as a "curswant" attribute:

> The `curswant` number is the preferred column when moving the cursor vertically.

(You'll also find the "curswant" attribute in the Dict returned by [`winsaveview()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#winsaveview%28%29).)

For instance, if you've moved horizontally on a long line to column 24, then vertically to a line that only has 17 columns, you'll see this:

```
:echo getcurpos()
[0, 39, 17, 0, 24]
```

So you can see you're on column 17, but "curswant" is column 24 and Vim will go to a column up to 24 if a line has enough columns.

After you press `$` and take another look at the `getcurpos()` output, you'll now see:

```
:echo getcurpos()
[0, 39, 17, 0, 2147483647]
```

So you'll see Vim is implementing the `$` behavior by setting "curswant" to a very large number, which is the largest number of columns Vim can possibly store in a single line.

(That number is actually 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, which is the maximum positive integer number you can store in a signed `int` type in the C language.)